# fixture 'page' not found - pytest playwright

Tags: python, pytest, playwright, playwright-python

I started learning playwright and from documentation (https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) tried to to run the following sample code:

```
import re
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect


def test_pp(page: Page):

    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")

    # Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
    expect(page).to_have_title(re.compile("Playwright"))

    # create a locator
    get_started = page.locator("text=Get Started")

    # Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
    expect(get_started).to_have_attribute("href", "/docs/intro")

    # Click the get started link.
    get_started.click()

    # Expects the URL to contain intro.
    expect(page).to_have_url(re.compile(".*intro"))
```

While running using command `pytest`, throwing following error:

```
file D:\play_wright\test\test_sample.py, line 5
  def test_pp(page: Page):
E       fixture 'page' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

D:\play_wright\test\test_sample.py:5
```

- `pytest-playwright` module (0.3.0) is installed. confirmed with `pip list` command
- Restarted Widows Machine
- playwright version - 1.27.1
- pytest - 6.2.1 (tried with 7.* as well)

Still getting the issue. please help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the pytest wrapper [pytest-playwright](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-playwright/) that provides default support for fixtures for all browsers like chromium, firefox and webkit.

```
$ pip install pytest-playwright
```

Comment: just upgraded python 3.11 with pw 1.39 
to python 3.12 .
immediately solved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. I ran this command, then restarted my command line and it started working.

```
playwright install-deps
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I tried above solution but did not work, still throws the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

> py.test test_.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: still same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try:
python3 -m pytest <test_file.py>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).